# CodeIgniter SQL Query Not Returning Logical Result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: Hotel Rooms Reservation ER Diagram]

I am using CodeIgniter Framework. I want to get all the available rooms on a particular date. The algorithm is as follows:

1) I shall give a date to check the availability of the room.

2) The System shall look into the table **"hotelbrancheshasreservations"** and shall select the **reservation ids** based on branch id and `status = 'active'.`

3) Then all the active **reservations** are selected and are joined with **reservation table**.

4) Only those reservations are extracted from **"reservation"** table after join which are not reserved on provided date and are active. There would be thousands of reservations in this table but that should be skipped.

5) Then the active reservations are joined with **"reservedrooms"** table and this will provide the rooms nos. which are although currently reserved but can be reserved for some other dates which have no conflict with current reservation date.

6) Finally, currently reserved rooms are also joined with **"hotelrooms"** table and all the available rooms returned for new reservation.

7) So a room can be reserved multiple times but with different dates.

I was not be able to develop a proper query in CodeIgniter to get all the available rooms if I provide some date like `$startdate = 2016-05-16` and `$enddate = 2016-05-27`.

The **datatype** in **MySQL** Db is `date`.

I am running the following query in **CodeIgniter**

```
function joinReserv($branchid, $startdate, $enddate, $db)
{
$status = "active";
$this->$db->trans_start();
$this->$db->select('reservationid, startdate, enddate, hotelbrancheshasreservations.status');
$this->$db->from('reservation');

$this->$db->where('( "'. $startdate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate  ) OR ( "'. $enddate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)');
$this->$db->where('(startdate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '") OR (enddate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '")');
$this->$db->join('hotelbrancheshasreservations', 'hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid = reservation.reservationid');
$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.status = '."'".$status."')");

$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid ='."'".$branchid."')");

$result = $this->$db->get()->result_array();
$this->$db->trans_complete();                   
return $result;
}
```

If I provide `startdate 2016-05-24` and `enddate 2016-05-26`, then it selects a reservation which is as follows:

```
[{"reservationid":"KHAN2016Q224","startdate":"2016-05-23","enddate":"2016-05-27","status":"pending"}]
```

This reservation should be skipped as it is not active in table **"hotelbrancheshasreservations"**

It selects those **reservations** which are within the provided dates but are not active. I want to select those reservations which are active and available on provided dates.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement right now will translate to

```
select reservationid, startdate, enddate, hotelbrancheshasreservations.status
from reservation
join hotelbrancheshasreservations 
on hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid 
   = reservation.reservationid
where ("$startdate" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate) 
  OR ("$enddate" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)
  AND (startdate BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate") 
  OR (enddate BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate")
  AND (hotelbrancheshasreservations.status = '$status')
  AND (hotelbrancheshasreservations.hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid = '$branchid');
```

so your `AND (hotelbrancheshasreservations.status = '$status')` will only apply to your last date-part `(enddate BETWEEN "$startdate" AND "$enddate")`.

You can use a `group_start()`/`group_end()` to add brackets around your two selects that contain the `OR`s or just add them directly:

```
$this->$db->select('reservationid, startdate, enddate, hotelbrancheshasreservations.status');
$this->$db->from('reservation');

$this->$db->where('(( "'. $startdate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate  ) 
                     OR ( "'. $enddate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate))');
$this->$db->where('((startdate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '") 
                     OR (enddate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '"))');
$this->$db->join('hotelbrancheshasreservations', 
 'hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid = reservation.reservationid');
$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.status = '."'".$status."')");
$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid 
                   ='."'".$branchid."')");
```

And please make sure your strings are clean/escaped if you use custom querys like this without the safety activerecord can provide.